# Kotlin: constructor reference for a parameterized type gives a compilation error

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to write in Kotlin something like the following Java code:

```
interface Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl1 implements Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl2 implements Provider {
}

enum Providers {
    ONE(ProviderImpl1::new),
    TWO(ProviderImpl2::new);

    private final Supplier<Provider> supplier;

    Providers(Supplier<Provider> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public Provider provider() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

This code compiles and works correctly: `Providers.ONE` produces an instance of `ProviderImpl1`, and `Providers.TWO` gives an instance of `ProviderImpl2`.

Here is what I could achieve in Kotlin:

```
interface Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl1 : Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl2: Provider {
}

enum class Providers(private val factory: Supplier<Provider>) {
    ONE(Supplier{ ProviderImpl1() }),
    TWO(Supplier{ ProviderImpl2() });

    fun provider(): Provider = factory.get()
}
```

It works, but in Java I'm able to use a constructor reference in an enum constructor. When I try to do the same in Kotlin, namely

```
ONE( ::ProviderImpl1 ),
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction0 but Supplier was expected

A lambda without explicit type does not work either:

```
ONE( ::ProviderImpl1 )
```

gives

> Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ProviderImpl1 but Supplier was expected

The question is: does Kotlin specification prohibit this (and if yes, why, as Java seems to cope with it), or this is just a temporary imperfection of the current Kotlin compiler?

My `build.gradle` has the following

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.61'
}
```

Kotlin language version is displayed by Idea (in project settings) as 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your `Supplier` to a lambda, this can be achieved quite nicely in Kotlin...

```
interface Provider
class ProviderImpl1 : Provider
class ProviderImpl2 : Provider

enum class Providers(private val supplier: () -> Provider) {
    ONE({ ProviderImpl1() }),
    TWO({ ProviderImpl2() });

    fun provider(): Provider = supplier.invoke()
}
```

The change here is to hand in a function that returns a `Provider` instance (which is essentially what a `Suppiler` is). This is nice because if, in the future, your `Provider` implementation needs some kind of configuration as it is being constructed, this lambda can handle that.

If your provider is stateless, you could get away with changing `Providers.provider()` into a `val`, where it will only be created once per enum type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kotlin.reflect.KFunction0` like the compilation error suggests instead of `java.util.function.Supplier` and then you can use the method reference.

Example:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction0

interface Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl1 : Provider {
}

class ProviderImpl2: Provider {
}

enum class Providers(private val factory: KFunction0<Provider>) {
    ONE(::ProviderImpl1),
    TWO(::ProviderImpl2);

    fun provider(): Provider = factory.call()
}
```

In this case the error message suggests that it expects an interface `kotlin.reflect.KFunction0` other than `java.util.function.Supplier`, so there is no prohibition for using method references in this constructor. You can use it, you just need to use the expected interface.